# Angular Universal with SSR, Google Lighthouse performance report

Tags: angular, performance, server-side-rendering, lighthouse, universal

I have an app created with Angular Universal to benefit from SEO improvements. The page loads very fast but when I do an analysis with Google Lighthouse I get a very low performance score? To what is due? Is it because it is rendered on the server and Google does not detect the js execution until it is loaded on the Client even though the website is already loaded?

I read about one issue related to this and Lighthouse v6.

Is that a real problem with Google Speed test and Angular Universal Apps?

If so, is there a solution to the problem or is there nothing to do?

Thanks for the help in advance.